# Cómo decir "college dropout"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

Aparentemente no hay una traducción exacta del frase inglés "college dropout" ... la mejor que podria encontrar es "estudiante que abandona la universidad antes de graduarse", cual me parece inelegante.

Hay un mejor frase idiomatica que puedo utilizar? O simplemente es que los del mundo español son mejores estudiantes que los que hablan inglés?

---

Apparently there's no exact translation of the English phrase "college dropout" ... the best I could find is "estudiante que abandona la universidad antes de graduarse", which seems inelegant to me.

Is there a better idiomatic phrase I could use? Or is it simply that people in the Spanish-speaking world are better students than English speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé si es formal, pero recuerdo que en México a veces dicen "desertor universitario" ([RAE](http://dle.rae.es/desertor)). Tal vez puede usar frases como, "Ella dejó la universidad" o "Él abandonó los estudios universitarios."

---

I'm not sure how formal it is, but I remember people in Mexico saying, "desertor universitario" ([RAE](http://dle.rae.es/desertor)). Maybe you could use phrases like, "Ella dejó la universidad" or "Él abandonó los estudios universitarios."

Answer (score 2):

La verdad, no creo que las personas que hablamos español seamos mejores estudiantes.  En mi experiencia, el término más usado es "no se graduó de la universidad", o más coloquialmente "no se graduó de la U".   A veces, se utiliza el término "bachiller", para referirse a alguien que solo se graduó de secundaria, y no terminó una carrera universitaria.

Que yo sepa, no existe un término específico en español que equivalga al "college dropout" en inglés.

---

Honestly, I don't think that the Spanish-speaking world are better students.  In my experience, the term used mostly is "no se graduó de la universidad", or more colloquially "no se graduó de la U".  Sometimes, the term "bachiller" is used to refer to somebody who only graduated from high-school, and didn't get a college degree.

To my knowledge, there is no specific term in Spanish that would be equivalent to "college dropout" in English.

Answer (score 1):

En Chile se utiliza el termino *Egresado*, para decir que terminó sus estudios universitarios pero que no se graduó.

Comment: La RAE dice que [un egresado es una persona que terminó sus estudios](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=06eD3z0jODXX2QYdUvMS), aunque no dice nada de la graduación en sí. Otras fuentes como (la dudosa wikipedia) dicen que el [egresado ha obtenido un título](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egresado), o por lo menos que ha terminado los estudios. Con títulos o símbolos o sin ellos, parece ser que el _egresado_ ha terminado los estudios, por lo que no puede ser considerado un **drop out**.

Comment: @Diego: Sin embargo es correcta la afirmación de Claudio García sobre el uso especial del término en Chile. Si tú dices "soy egresado de Pedagogía" das a entender que egresaste pero no te has graduado. Aunque concuerdo con que eso no equivale a un drop out.)

Answer (score 0):

Como en México es menos común ir a la universidad, por lo general cuando se dice en español:

> Él no se graduó.

se infiere que:

```
no se graduó de la universidad / no terminó sus estudios / nunca empezó la universidad.
```

o también `"No terminó/acabó la universidad"` puede acercarse mas a tu definición de "estudiante que abandona la universidad antes de graduarse".